# SAS Import from .CSV with line break

Tags: sas

I have .csv with line break and want to import in to SAS, But am facing the problems with data having like CUSTOMER with space (wrap text). Please help me how to overcome from this problem, Similar way I have some other variables,  If I import mannualy its working fine.Please find the example below. See SLN PJ0136 to know the problem.

```
SLN     MOD PM  NE      CUSTOMER
32121   GG  1   1   AVAILABLE UPON REQUEST
71403   EN  1   0   JET SUPPORT SERVICE INC.
305173  EN  1   1   UNKNOWN / COTTONWOOD, LLC / J SUPPORT SERVICE, INC.
PJ0136  PS  0   0   "UNKNOWN / GROUP B-50 INC AA
                    TC0004   anada CSC Europe
                    Inglewood Ava" 
EB0162  RG  0   0   ATR
```

I used infile to import

```
DATA WORK.test1;
%let _EFIERR_ = 0; 
INFILE 'C:\Users\26631.IELPWC\Downloads\test.csv'
       delimiter = ',' MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=2 ;

    INFORMAT
        SLN  $CHAR6. MOD $CHAR2. PM  BEST1.  NE BEST1. CUSTOMER $CHAR82. ;
    FORMAT
        SLN  $CHAR6.  MOD  $CHAR2. PM  BEST1.  NE   BEST1. CUSTOMER  $CHAR82. ;
    INPUT
        SLN $  MOD $  PM NE CUSTOMER $ ;

   if _ERROR_ then call symputx('_EFIERR_',1);
RUN;
```

Please see the wrong output

```
32121   GG  1   1   AVAILABLE UPON REQUEST
71403   EN  1   0   JET SUPPORT SERVICE INC.
305173  EN  1   1   UNKNOWN / COTTONWOOD, LLC / J SUPPORT SERVICE, INC.
PJ0136  PS  0   0   "UNKNOWN / GROUP B-50 INC AA
TC0004      .   .   
24719       .   .   
"       .   .   
EB0162  RG  0   0   ATR
```

Comment: I have no idea what 'if I import manually works fine" means.  Are you using `PROC IMPORT`, the import wizard, something else?

Comment: Joe yes, by using import wizard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your input data is in the following format:

```
SLN,MOD,PM,NE,CUSTOMER
32121,GG,1,1,AVAILABLE UPON REQUEST
71403,EN,1,0,JET SUPPORT SERVICE INC.
305173,EN,1,1,"UNKNOWN / COTTONWOOD, LLC / J SUPPORT SERVICE, INC."
PJ0136,PS,0,0,"UNKNOWN / GROUP B-50 INC AA
TC0004   anada CSC Europe
Inglewood Ava"
EB0162,RG,0,0,ATR
```

The following SAS code will produce required output:

```
data TEST (drop=_TMP_:);
  format SLN $6. MOD $2. PM 8. NE 8. CUSTOMER $82. _TMP_STR $100.;
  infile 'input.csv' truncover firstobs=2 dlm=',' dsd lrecl=10000;
  input SLN MOD PM NE _TMP_STR @;
  _TMP_COUNT=0;
  do until(mod(_TMP_COUNT, 2) = 0);
    CUSTOMER=catx('0A'x, CUSTOMER, _TMP_STR);
    _TMP_COUNT=_TMP_COUNT + countc(_TMP_STR, '"');
    if mod(_TMP_COUNT, 2) then do;
      input _TMP_STR;
    end;
  end;
  CUSTOMER=dequote(CUSTOMER);
run;
```

*Please note* that the value for **CUSTOMER** column where `SLN='PJ0136'` is multiline (Unix style). You can remove this by changing function `catx(...)` acordingly.